# Building a backwards compatible macOS bundle in XCode for Unity3D

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine

I have a question regarding building plugin bundles for Unity3D in XCode.

I am implementing a plugin that accesses Apple's new GameController API, parts of which are only available for macOS 11 and above.

The Deployment Target for the bundle is set to 10.15 so that the plugin still works for macOS 10.15 builds, and the part of code that queries GameController info is wrapped with Objective-C's @available check:

```
if(@available(macOS 11.0, iOS 14.0, tvOS 14.0, *))
{
    ...
}
```

However, for some reason this expression always appears to result in 'false' when using a Deployment Target of 10.15, regardless of using the plugin inside a Unity Project that runs on a macOS 11 platform. (When I set the Deployment Target to 11, the code executes again but Unity fails to import the bundle when running on macOS 10.15).

My question is whether this is the correct way to build backwards compatible bundles. I know that @available is a runtime check for versions, but I am not sure if this still applies to bundles.

**Edit:**

Following up on this, I ran a test in a fresh Objective-C application that imports a bundle at runtime and invokes a function through Apple's equivalent of a DLL import. Both the bundle and the application have been build with 10.15 as Deployment Target. The OS that the application runs on is 11 Beta (Big Sur). The @available check correctly detects that the OS version is 11: http://img.desu.link/?i=z5KW8IJCk1.png

I then imported the same bundle into our Unity project running on the same OS and invoked the same method from C# via an extern method with the DllImport attribute, but in that case @available check inside the bundle fails: http://img.desu.link/?i=DDZ9yCtG4V.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like macOS Big Sur reports its version as 10.16 if the application is linked against 10.15 or older SDK. The Unity version I am using is built using macOS 10.14 SDK, and thus the check fails.

Checking against 10.16 in the @available check resolves this issue.

See https://eclecticlight.co/2020/07/21/big-sur-is-both-10-16-and-11-0-its-official/